# Importing a function that uses module-level variables

Tags: python, import, module

Example:

```
$ cat m1.py
a = 1
def f():
    print a

$ cat m2.py 
from m1 import f
a = 2
f()
```

I want `python m2.py` to print `2` when I run it, but it prints `1`.

Do I have to make `f` take `a` as an argument or is there a better way of achieving this? I'm trying to code DRY and reuse the same function in a different "environment" this way. It would make sense to define `a` inside `f`, as well, if I could override it upon importing.

Another way I thought of is:

```
$ cat m1.py
a = 1
def make_f(a):
    def f():
        print a
    return f

f = make_f(a)

$ cat m2.py 
from m1 import make_f
a = 2
f = make_f(a)
f()
```

This works as needed, but are there more concise ways?

**Edit:** Thanks for the answers so far; I don't think I can clarify anything by providing a more realistic example, but I'd say that the reason why I'm even asking this is because in my mind there is a distinction between the actual arguments of `f` (which it would use the same way in both modules) and the "environment" `a`, which should differ. May be I shouldn't really distinguish (judging by the need to use different values of `a` in different modules) but the distinction makes sense based on the meaning `a` bears.

**Edit 2:** I gave it another thought and concluded that I probably want to use a closure, the reason being that I don't want other functions in each module to have to supply `a` when calling `f`. This is, I guess, the observable, non-virtual distinction that is there.

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand you properly) -- Try this:

```
#m2.py
from m1 import f
import m1
m1.a = 2
f()
```

However, I should mention that the very fact that you need to do this throws off all sorts of bells and whistles in my head -- This seems like a very bad design.

Comment: What would be good design then? Is the second way I posted also bad? Could you please elaborate, because I care about writing good code. And yes, you understand me properly.

Comment: It seems to me that the environment that calls a function shouldn't effect the functions behavior.  That violates encapsulation.  If your function does need to react to the calling environment, I might pass in a dictionary which describes the environment or something.  However, with this very limited example, it's difficult to know what you're really trying to achieve.

Comment: @LevLevitsky In general, if you want to parametrize a function, add a parameter. Your example is quite abstract, but it seems the sanest approach in any case. Closures are useful, but rarely so, and usually only if you pass the closure around.

Comment: @mgilson I've tried to provide some context (not of the code, though, but rather of my thoughts about it), but I feel like it won't change your answer much.

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- You're right, it doesn't really change my thoughts :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine that your code is more complex than this example, so I'd recommend that you try using a class:

**YourClass.py**

```
class YourClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1):
        self.a = a

    def f(self):
        print self.a
```

**YourOtherFile.py**

```
from YourClass import YourClass

o = YourClass(a=2)  # Without explicitly setting `a=2`, `a` defaults to `1`
o.f()
```

Without much more context, I can't offer any more advice.

Comment: Of course, a class with only one method besides `__init__` shouldn't be a class. See [Stop Writing Classes](http://pyvideo.org/video/880/stop-writing-classes).

Comment: @delnan: I don't think `m1.py` contains just *one* function named `f`. But then again, without seeing the full picture, I'm just making assumptions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not necessarily disagreeing, just wanted to point that out. Preventing a class that isn't is worth a potentially misaimed comment IMHO :)

Comment: Actually, it really is about just one function. `m1` contains more, but only `f` depends on `a`.